# Flickr: How to generate the Authentication Signature?

Tags: authentication, oauth, flickr

All I want is to receive a request token from flicker. 
 I'll worry about the follow-on authorizing process later.

Here's the request-token URL that I've generated:

```
https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?oauth_version=1&oauth_consumer_key=<32-char key goes here>&oauth_timestamp=1413311480.09318&oauth_callback=http://www.amourineTech.com/oauth/test&oauth_nonce=0175EEC29A144BE3A496D4D5486CAC54&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
```

I disseminated the url string here:

```
https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?
oauth_version=1&
oauth_consumer_key=<...key code...>&
oauth_timestamp=1413311480.09318&
oauth_callback=http://www.amourineTech.com/oauth/test&
oauth_nonce=0175EEC29A144BE3A496D4D5486CAC54&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
```

This follows what flickr does on their dev site: 
[image]

Here's what I get when via the browser:

> oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature

There appears to be a step missing here. 
How to I generate the authentication signature?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty tricky, and the included image doesn't really explain it well.

It does mention that you need to create a "base string" and apply a HMAC-SHA1 signature. This means that you need to concatenate your request method (GET, POST, PUT, etc), host name (like http://www.microsoft.com), and query parameters (like oauth_nonce=394938BAC&oauth_timestamp=....) together in a string, and then run HMAC-SHA1 encryption on that string. The resulting {hash} is a string and you'll set oauth_signature={hash}

This link does a pretty thorough job of explaining the issue -

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signature

My advice would be to find a good oAuth framework in whatever language you're coding in. oAuth is actually really tricky and a total pain to roll your own.

Comment: Twitter link is 404.

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature